# Check stdout of async Ansible task

Tags: ansible

How can you `failed_when` based on the `stdout` of an async Ansible task? I've tried variations of:

```
- name: Run command
  command: arbitrary_command
  async: 3600
  poll: 10
  register: result
  failed_when: "Finished 'command'" in result.stdout
```

This results in:

```
fatal: [localhost] => error while evaluating conditional: "Finished 'command'" in result.stdout
```

Comment: The error message is supremely un-useful (see: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5356).  In this case its because `result` does not have the attribute `stdout`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible: Perform a failed\_when: on an async task based on a value from stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39069619/ansible-perform-a-failed-when-on-an-async-task-based-on-a-value-from-stdout)

Answer (score 13):

Obtain status of asynchronous task with `async_status` once the task is complete:

```
- name: Run command
  command: arbitrary_command
  async: 3600
  poll: 10
  register: result_async

- name: Check command
  async_status: jid="{{ result_async.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: result
  failed_when: result.finished != 1 or "Finished 'command'" not in result.stdout
```

Comment: This took a fair bit of tinkering to figure out. Hopefully it saves someone time!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Fraser Harris. I couldn't really understand what was happening. I could see in the Ansible output that the variable was defined with content... But like you pointed out, you need to use the async_status to get the variable even though you can see it as defined after the task execution in the ansible output.